# How to link testlink with jira?

Tags: testlink, jira

I have created test cases in test link and have reported the issues in jira. I want to link the issue no with the test link. How can this be done?

Let me know if you really know this.

Comment: Manually or through automation script?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one link which I followed to connect TestLink with JIRA

http://santexgroup.com/blog/integrating-jira-with-testlink-3/

This may also help you out

https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/1842435-271397324

Comment: Hi log_file, I'm sure there's good content in these links, but we tend to avoid link-only answers. Basically, an answer should stand on its own without linking to external sources. At the same time, there's a fine line to be walked for copying content. Would you be able to make this answer an actual answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through "Bug Tracking" in the test case which helps us to link directly through JIRA

Goto **Test Execution** 
Click on test case not the test suite 
On your right hand side check for the Bug Management and hover on it you will find a link which opens up a pop up asking for the BUG ID. Please give the bug ID which is relevant to that particular test cases and save it. 
Then the Build along with the Relevant Bug is shown with the URL in that particular test cases.